# How to change the font to bold,italic,font color of uitextview

Tags: ios, uitextview

I have a uitextview. I want to select the content in the uitextview and make it bold,italics,change colour and add the line spacing.I want to save  the content .
After saving i want to see the changes.Is there any way to do it

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this,

```
 textView.textColor = [UIColor orangeColor];

 UIFontDescriptor * fontD = [textView.font.fontDescriptor fontDescriptorWithSymbolicTraits:UIFontDescriptorTraitBold | UIFontDescriptorTraitItalic ];

 textView.font = [UIFont fontWithDescriptor:fontD size:0];
```

`size:0` means 'keep the size as is'

Hope this will help :)